# What is the meaning of the name "Wilber" in English?

Tags: american-english, names

I'm thinking of picking *Wilber* as my English given name recently, since it has similar pronunciation with my Chinese given name.

But I'm not sure about the meaning of *Wilber* in English, especially in American English.

Is it fit for Asians?

Comment: It's usually spelt as [**Wilbur**](http://www.behindthename.com/name/wilbur)

Comment: "Is it a good name?" is a matter of opinion, and would be off-topic. I've edited that part of the question out.

Comment: See [here](http://www.behindthename.com/name/wilbur) and [here](http://www.parentdish.co.uk/babynames/) (you'll have to type in *Wilbur*). Although I'm not sure this is on topic here, I have to admit I love the origins of this name!

Comment: I like the name Wilbur a lot; it has good historical associations (Wilbur Wright) and a solid, manly, reliable feel.  However: 1) it's very old-fashioned (this could be good or bad - it's up to you!) and 2) the first thing most Americans will think of is **not** Wilbur Wright, but Wilbur the pig from [Charlotte's Web](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charlotte%27s_Web), a beloved classic children's book and movie.

Comment: [**Wilbur**](http://www.babynamespedia.com/meaning/Wilbur) is a very old fashioned name, it has more than one meaning and there are many variations. (Click on the red words!) I think of Wilbur the cat in the *Winnie the Witch* children book series. Definitely "quirky". Avoid being nicknamed *Willy* at all costs! :)

Comment: A more conventional choice would be William, but be different! Go for Wilbur! Just don't be surprised if an American assumes you are about 70 years old.

Comment: @Mike Your words make a lot of sence.

Comment: Associations can be just as strong as literal meaning. 'Wilbur' doesn't have a literal meaning in English (at least none without lots of research). But in most American's minds 'Wilbur' is associated with [a 1950's TV show 'Mr. Ed'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mister_Ed), a comedy about a talking horse, whose owner is named 'Wilbur'. When I hear the name 'Wilbur, my first impression is of the horse speaking this name in it's goofy comedic country-bumpkin voice. It is a very uncommon name nowadays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very few given names have any separate meaning apart from the name itself.

*Wilbur* has no special meaning in English.  It might derive connotations from others who have gone by that name, but it does not actually “mean” anything in any denotational sense.

The rare exceptions are people’s names that actually have an identically spelled common noun in current (or whilom) use, like *Dawn, Joy, Bonnie, Linda, Amber, Hazel, Gloria, Raven, Lark, Dove, Buck, Cat, Kit, Kitty, Hawk, Wolf, Bear, Tiger, Fox, Felix, Pansy, Grace, Lily, Gay, Clementine, Jade, Jewel, Sky, Faith, Hope, Charity, Justice, Victor, Alma, Alba, Angel, Duke, Earl, Prince, Rex, Regis, Regina, River, Rock, Jewel, Pearl, Ruby, Jasper, Violet, Brandy, Iris, Olive, Flora, Daisy,* or *Rose*.  You are — or originally, *were* but the memory may have become lost — intended to think of the common noun in association with that person.

Others are (probably) mere accidents, like *Ray, Jay, Art, Alf, Ham, Jack, Max, Herb, Dean, Dale, Lance, Nick, Chad, Troy, Frank, Bill, Rob, Bob, Mark, Chuck, Jess, Bud, Jake, Tip, Tor,* or *Dick*, or adjectives like *Randy* or *Corny* or even *Tony*. You are not intended to think of the common noun in those cases.  Many of these unintended ones are just nicknames, not legal first names.

However, *Wilbur* just isn’t of these, because there aren’t any “wilburs” in this world that mean something else.  *Wilbur* just means Wilbur; that is to say, some person’s personal name and nothing more.

Comment: Very few _have_ may be strictly correct, but I dare say that most names _had_ a separate meaning at some (early) point in their career. A quick search reveals that [Wilbur](http://www.behindthename.com/name/wilbur) may be derived from _wild boar_ - although many of these sites are not very trustworthy. It doesn't mean most names lack an etymology though, as your answer seems to imply.

Comment: @oerkelens: true, but probably irrelevant. Most people are unaware of the etymologies of the names they meet - I suspect in many cases, even of their own names.